# Multiline string in VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to use get multiline string from parent component and give it to child component as prop.
So, i want to get text display as:

Some

multiline

String

How can I do it?

Parentcomponent:

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="articles">
      <Article
        v-for="article in articles"
        :key="article.id"
        :articleText="article.articleText"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import ModelButton from "~/components/basic/ModelButton";
import Article from "~/components/common/Article";
export default {
  components: {
    Article,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      articles: [
        {
          articleText: `Some 
                        multi
                        lines`,
        },
       ]
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

And my child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="article">
    <div class="article-text">
      <p>{{ articleText }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    articleText: String,
  },
};
</script>
```

Also I tried to use `<plaintext>` instead of `<p>`, but I got only one line and text was pretty ugly and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution and it is using `<pre>` tag. And setting font-family for it.

```
<template>
      <div class="article">
        <div class="article-text">
          <pre>{{ articleText }}</pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      props: {
        articleText: String,
      },
    };
    </script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.article {
  &-text {
    pre {
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

It's quite uncomfortable to work with it. But it will be fine, if you can found better solutions for it.

### Updated:

These styles can help you to work with `<pre>` tag:

```
pre {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using escape sequences in your text

```
articles: [
        {
          articleText: `Some\n
                        multi\n
                        lines`,
        },
       ]
```